# How to retrieve particular images from folder, indicated by a string list with image names

Tags: python

I have a general question and no code, since I have no clear idea on how to do this.

I have a folder with many different images (.jpg) and also a csv file that holds the different image names in a string list. Each list has a different image name combination, for example:

str_all1=['01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg', '04_2.jpg','10_1.jpg']

str_all2=[ '10_1.jpg','01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg','03_1.jpg']

str_all3=['06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg','01_2.jpg', '04_2.jpg', '10_1.jpg']

In the csv file, each element from the above lists corresponds to a column. Also, str_all1 is in row one, str_all2 in row two, etc.

The idea is to select one random row from the cvs file (since one row holds the list of images that will be presented to one participant) and to match the name of the image to its actual image (in the image folder) that I would like to display.

How can I use this list from the csv file to retrieve the images from a folder and present them?

Answer (score 0):

You need the **random** module.  You can use `random.choice` to randomly pick a list.

**Example:**

```
import random

s = [['01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg', '04_2.jpg','10_1.jpg'], [ '10_1.jpg','01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg','03_1.jpg'], ['06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg','01_2.jpg', '04_2.jpg', '10_1.jpg'] ]
print random.choice(s)
```

Comment: I need to randomly pick this list from the csv file, so I would have to randomly choose a row that goes through each element of the list (through each column). The idea is that when item from row 1 column 1 is identified, it retrieves it in the image folder so I can display if to my participants.